# Complex Grouping : Array Reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

i really struggle with array.reduce() and i think in this case i'm not sure if i've got the right approach. Typically i have a starting array and i know what i need to end up with but i can't seem to get the grouping right.

This is the starting array

```
[
{ name: 'Home' },
{
    name: 'Services',
    menu: [
    { name: 'Painting' },
    { name: 'Decorating' },
    { name: 'Lawn mowing', submenu: 'Garden' },
    { name: 'Tree surgery', submenu: 'Garden' },
    { name: 'Edging', submenu: 'Garden' }
    ]
},
{ name: 'Contact' }
]
```

and what i'd like to end up with is this

```
[
{ name: 'Home' },
{
    name: 'Services',
    menu: [
    { name: 'Painting' },
    { name: 'Decorating' },
    {
        name: 'Garden',
        menu: [
        { name: 'Lawn mowing', submenu: 'Garden' },
        { name: 'Tree surgery', submenu: 'Garden' },
        { name: 'Edging', submenu: 'Garden' }
        ]
    }
    ]
},
{ name: 'Contact' }
]
```

So i'd like to be able to group by anything that has a submenu and then return a new sorted array.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following recursive approach:

```js
function reduce(array) {
    const result = [];
    // object to keep grouped submenus
    const grouped = {};
    for (let i of array) {
        if (i.menu) {
            // if the current item has a nested menu we call reduce recursively
            result.push({
                name: i.name,
                menu: reduce(i.menu)
            });
        } else if (i.submenu) {
            // if it has a submenu we put it to the grouped object
            if (grouped[i.submenu]) {
                grouped[i.submenu].menu.push(i)
            } else {
                grouped[i.submenu] = {
                    name: i.submenu,
                    menu: [i]
                };
                result.push(grouped[i.submenu]);
            }
        } else {
            // else we just copy it to the result array
            result.push(i);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

const array = [
    { name: 'Home' },
    {
        name: 'Services',
        menu: [
            { name: 'Painting' },
            { name: 'Decorating' },
            { name: 'Lawn mowing', submenu: 'Garden' },
            { name: 'Tree surgery', submenu: 'Garden' },
            { name: 'Edging', submenu: 'Garden' }
        ]
    },
    { name: 'Contact' }
];

console.log(reduce(array));
```

Comment: Thanks Kirill! this is awesome!

Answer (score 2):

You could reduce the array by looking for submenu and take this for a seach of a node in the actual level.

If not just add either a new object or one with a menu from the recursive call.

```js
function mapSubmenu(result, { name, menu, submenu }) {
    if (submenu) {
        var parent = result.find(({ name }) => name === submenu);
        if (!parent) result.push(parent = { name: submenu, menu: [] });
        parent.menu.push({ name, submenu });
    } else {
        result.push(menu
            ? { name, menu: menu.reduce(mapSubmenu, []) }
            : { name }
        );
    }
    return result;
}

var data = [{ name: 'Home' }, { name: 'Services', menu: [{ name: 'Painting' }, { name: 'Decorating' }, { name: 'Lawn mowing', submenu: 'Garden' }, { name: 'Tree surgery', submenu: 'Garden' }, { name: 'Edging', submenu: 'Garden' }] }, { name: 'Contact' }],
    result = data.reduce(mapSubmenu, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```